# Removing element from a list on python based on position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style

I was just wondering how would I be able to remove a part of a list purely based on position.

```
rando = keywords[random.randint(0, 14)]
h = 0
for h in range(len(keywords)):
    if rando == keywords[h]:
        position = h

realAns = definitions[position]
```

I tried

```
rando.remove[h]
```

but it didn't seem to work :(

What code would I be able to use to remove that keyword (not definition) once correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also want to get what your removing, you can do:

```
rando.pop(h)
```

Otherwise just do:

```
del rando[h]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `del` and specify the element you want to delete with the `index`.

```
>>> a=[i for i in range(1,11)]
>>>a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> del a[0]
>>> a
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>>
```

In addition you can also use `pop` , **`pop` return deleted element**.

```
>>> a=[i for i in range(1,11)]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> a.pop(1)
2
>>> a
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>>
```

If you not specified any argument in pop it removes the last item.

```
>>> a=[i for i in range(1,11)]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> a.pop()
10
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

Comment: This message comes up when I try to implement del:
del randKey[h]
TypeError: 'str' object doesn't support item deletion